# Simple complex contour integral $\int_C \frac{1}{1+z^2} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate $$\int_C \frac{1}{1+z^2} dz$$ along the line segment from $z=1$ to $z=1+i$.

My solution:

Parametrization $p(t) = 1+t, \:\: 0\leq t \leq i$ with derivative $1$. We thus get:  $$\int_C \frac{1}{1+z^2} dz = \int_{0}^{i} \frac{1}{1+(1+t)^2} dt = tan^{-1}(1+t)|_{0}^{i} = tan^{-1}(1+i)-tan^{-1}(1)$$

This is however wrong. So my question is, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the parametrisation is something that you can improve.

Set

$$z(t) = 1 + it ~~~~~~~ t\in [0, 1]$$

$$z'(t) = i$$

Hence use the formula:

$$\int_{\gamma_1}f(z)\ \text{d}z = \int_{\gamma}(f(z(t))z'(t)\ \text{d}t = \int_0^1 \frac{i\ \text{d}t}{1 + (1+it)^2}$$

The denominator is not:

$$1 + (1+it)^2 = 1 + 1 + 2it - t^2 = -t^2 + 2it + 2$$

Poles are at

$$t^2 - 2it - 2 = 0 ~~~~~~~ \to t = \begin{cases} i + 1 \\ i-1 \end{cases}$$

Hence the integral can be written as

$$i\int_0^1 \frac{\text{d}t}{(t-i-1)(t-i+1)}$$

Now you should be able to evaluate it with normal integration techniques.

Can you proceed?

**Final Solution**

By splitting the integral as you did in the comment below, you will get two really trivial integrals:

$$\frac{i}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\text{d}t}{t - (i+1)} = \frac{1}{8}\left(-\pi - i\ln(4)\right)$$

and

$$\frac{i}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\text{d}t}{t - (i-1))} = \frac{1}{8} \left(-\pi +i \log \left(\frac{25}{4}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$

You really can obtain those results in the trivial way in which you obtained your results in what you tried.

Now, the final result is the difference:

$$\frac{1}{8}\left(-\pi - i\ln(4)\right) - \frac{1}{8} \left(-\pi +i \log \left(\frac{25}{4}\right)+4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) = \frac{1}{8}\left(-i\ln(25) + 4\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$

Notice that you can funny manipulate. For example: $25 = 5^2 \to \ln(25) = 2\ln(5)$ et cetera.

Comment: Then we get $\frac{i}{2}( \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dt}{t-(i+1)}-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dt}{t-(i-1)})$ and the second integral is 0 since the point $i-1$ is not contained in the path?

Comment: @Lozansky Sorry my bad: I meant "usual integration techniques", not "residues". You can really integrate easily that functions. I added the details too.

Comment: It should be the negative of that. Also, did you choose the principal value of the argument?

Comment: @Lozansky Maybe there is a sign error, somewhere. But what you have to do is just integrate. You will obtain a log and an arctan function. No residues is required, because your path is defined from $0$ to $1$!